# why GDB is not printing arrays?

Tags: gdb

When running some of my binaries I found it strange that GDB does not dump the arrays and I don't know why this only happens in some of the executables.

The declaration is very simple:

```
 tbl_account_t       accounts[MAX_ACCOUNTS];
```

When I print arrays (just any array), I get this:

```
(gdb) print accounts
$16 = 0x618d20 <accounts>
```

Confirming the variable type, everything is ok:

```
(gdb) ptype accounts
type = struct tbl_account {
    unsigned short email_len;
    unsigned short password_len;
    char auto_log_in;
    char reserved_char[3];
    int reserved_int;
    char email[64];
    char password[25];
} []
(gdb)
```

I do have the data in it:

```
(gdb) print accounts[1]
$18 = {email_len = 16, password_len = 3, auto_log_in = 0 '\000', reserved_char = "\000\000", reserved_int = 0, email = "abra@cadabra.com", '\000' <repeats 47 times>, 
  password = "123", '\000' <repeats 21 times>}
(gdb)
```

With "print accounts" command I was expecting GDB to dump the **entire** contents of the array, like it does in other executables. Why does this happen ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't quite have the full answer but I suspect that if you share more of your code we can figure it out.  It appears that gdb does not know the length of your array.

Consider this program

```
struct tbl_account {
    unsigned short email_len;
    unsigned short password_len;
    char auto_log_in;
    char reserved_char[3];
    int reserved_int;
    char email[64];
    char password[25];
};


int main(int argc, char* agv[])
{

tbl_account table[10];
tbl_account* table_ptr = table;
return 0;
}
```

Now the gdb session

```
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4006e5: file junk.cpp, line 22.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /tmp/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, agv=0x7fffffffdfe8) at junk.cpp:22
22  tbl_account* table_ptr = table;
(gdb) n
23  return 0;
(gdb) ptype table_ptr
type = struct tbl_account {
    unsigned short email_len;
    unsigned short password_len;
    char auto_log_in;
    char reserved_char[3];
    int reserved_int;
    char email[64];
    char password[25];
} *
(gdb) ptype table
type = struct tbl_account {
    unsigned short email_len;
    unsigned short password_len;
    char auto_log_in;
    char reserved_char[3];
    int reserved_int;
    char email[64];
    char password[25];
} [10]
```

Note how the ptype of the pointer is indicated by the '*'.  We can also see that the array type is indicated by the [10].  In my example, the array size is included and gdb will print each element.  For some reason, in your example the size of the array is not included.   Perhaps it is an `extern` variable?

Since gdb isn't certain of the size of the array, it just prints it as a pointer value. As a worked around try casting

`(gdb) p (tbl_account[10])accounts`

Comment: Thanks a lot, you helped me to find out what the problem was. I did not have the header "constants.h" included in main.c and this is where MAX_ACCOUNTS is declared in my source code. For GCC this is not a problem, so there is no compilation error. But  apparently GDB does not look up symbol definition on lower hierarchies of includes. By adding #include "constants.h" into the main.c itself GDB could find out the size of accounts[] array and now it prints it fine.

Comment: I found the real cause of this. It was not the include "constants.h". It happens that I was tracing the code inside a library function (my own library, but it is a completely different shared object) and that library uses this declaration: "extern tbl_account_t accounts[]" , this is why only pointer was printed.

Comment: Ha! Nailed it with the extern guess

Answer (score 1):

You can also manually tell GDB how many entries to print using '@'.
This works better if your array is not statically allocated or you just want to examine specific set of entries in the array.

```
struct tbl_account {
    int id;
    char email[64];
    char password[25];
};

int main(void)
{
    struct tbl_account table[] = {
            {1, "abc", "1234"}, 
            {2, "def", "5678"}, 
            {3, "ghi", "1011"}, 
            {4, "jkl", "1213"}};

    return 0;
}
```

And then tell GDB to print first 3 entries in the array

```
(gdb) p table[0]@3
$3 = {{
    id = 1, 
    email = "abc", '\000' <repeats 60 times>, 
    password = "1234", '\000' <repeats 20 times>
  }, {
    id = 2, 
    email = "def", '\000' <repeats 60 times>, 
    password = "5678", '\000' <repeats 20 times>
  }, {
    id = 3, 
    email = "ghi", '\000' <repeats 60 times>, 
    password = "1011", '\000' <repeats 20 times>
  }}
```

If you are interested in only index 2-3 for e.g, You could do -

```
(gdb) p table[2]@2
$5 = {{
    id = 3, 
    email = "ghi", '\000' <repeats 60 times>, 
    password = "1011", '\000' <repeats 20 times>
  }, {
    id = 4, 
    email = "jkl", '\000' <repeats 60 times>, 
    password = "1213", '\000' <repeats 20 times>
  }}
```